# Add-on Not showing up/Working

Tags: add-on, customization

I am a true newbie to Blender. I tried installing an addon and every time I try to install it, it fails to show up in the addon bar. The addon that isn't working is MMD Tools

Comment: What version of Blender are you using and which version (link?) of MMD Tools did you try to install? Seems like there are different forks of it.

Comment: put a screenshot of your problem where it shows which mmd tool you are trying to install, that would help a lot for a solution to your problem